# Pop-up blocker needed

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security

Is there any pop-up block program that I can run while using my TorBrowser? Or is there a program that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Tor or the Tor Browser Bundle does not include a special program or plugin which deals with pop-up blocking. Firefox has a builtin pop-up blocker which works for a large amount of pup-ups. Some websites can work around this blocker and open pop-ups. For this case you'll to set up special plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Installing plugins may compromise your anonymity which is why Tor doesn't come with any... until someone writes an open source, privacy-verified plugin to deal with javascript popups you can either disable javascript or risk installing a pop up blocking plugin which may reveal your computer's identity